# Gallery Block Refactor Gutenberg Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

according to the dev note bellow:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/08/20/gallery-block-refactor-dev-note/

the HTML structure of the Gutenberg gallery block has been changed from a UL > LI to FIGURE > FIGURE. That is okay, but now, we don't have a CSS class on each gallery item as we had before, I know that via CSS this is not a problem to select child elements on this gallery, but the problem is when we have to make some changes into the block structure via PHP using the block hook render_block, I was selecting gallery items by using its classes names, and now, this is not possible. Is anyone here facing this same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each Image within a Gallery block can have its own custom CSS class assigned under `Advanced > Additional CSS class(es)`. The custom names are then stored in the block attributes, which are accessible via PHP when doing custom parsing/rendering the block.

[image: Gallery Block]

The class name is applied to the HTML as

```html
<figure class="wp-block-gallery">
    <figure class="wp-block-image size-large my-custom-class">
        <img/>
    </figure>
    <figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
        <img/>
    </figure>
</figure>
```

I assume in PHP you are using [parse_blocks()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/) or your own custom function to render the content.

Comment: Hi S.Walsh, thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this is not a good solution for the end-user, we can't suggest to the end-user to put those classes or something like that, I'm working on a theme it will be sold on theme marketplaces, so, we should handle everything by our end. Best.

Comment: @LeandroBerg No worries, I would add this extra info to your original question, as I would have answered differently if I knew you were creating a product and I thought you were looking for a way to re-add your own CSS classes to the items in the Gallery